# Automate tkinter file dialogues for functional testing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-unittest, functional-testing

I have a Python tkinter script which I want to run some functional tests on. The script includes both `tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename()` and `tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename()`, so I wanted a part of the test which uploads/downloads a file. I tried to use `pyautogui` to try to automate mouse clicks and to send keys to try to automate these actions, but doing so didn't work (nothing visible changed on the screen and no file was loaded).

### Functional Test attempt with pyautogui

```py
class TestOrganizeAttendance(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.organizer = AttendanceOrganizer()
    ...

    def test_attendance_organizer_window_operation(self):
        ...
        #User clicks button and their computer's files appear
        self.organizer.upload_file_button.invoke()
        self.assertIn(
            "explorer.exe", [p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()])

        #User selects a file to be uploaded
        filepath = os.path.abspath(
            os.path.join('.', 'tests', 'sample_attendance.csv'))
        pyautogui.PAUSE = 2.5
        pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'd')
        pyautogui.typewrite(filepath)
        pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
        ....
```

### Script

```py
class AttendanceOrganizer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.upload_file_button = tkinter.Button(
            self.root, text="Upload File", command=self.upload_file)
        self.download_file_button = tkinter.Button(
            self.root, text="Download File", command=self.download_file)
        ...

    def upload_file(self):
        self.details_var.set(
            value="Select a file to upload")
        filetypes = [('Comma Separated Values', '.csv')]
        filepath = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(
            parent=self.root, filetypes=filetypes)
        if not (filepath and os.path.splitext(filepath)[-1] == '.csv'):
            return
        self.upload_var.set(value=filepath)
        self.details_var.set(
            value=f"File Uploaded\t{self.details_var.get()}")
        with open(filepath, encoding='utf-16') as file:
            self.values = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter='\t'))
            del self.values[0]
        self.organize_data_button.config(state='normal')

    def download_file(self):
        filetypes = [('Comma Separated Values', '.csv')]
        filepath = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(
            parent=self.root, filetypes=filetypes)
        with open(f"{filepath}.csv", 'w', newline='') as file:
            fieldnames = ["Last", "First", "Joined", "Left"]
            writer = csv.DictWriter(
                file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter='\t')
            writer.writeheader()
            for item in self.data:
                writer.writerow(self.data[item])

    ...
```

Comment: I don't know how to help you if you show only testing code without program which you try to test. Better create minimal working code with `askopenfilename` and your test so we could simply copy and run it - to see problem and text ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the above code in `functional_tests.py` is that both `tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename` and `tkinter.filedialog.asksaveaskfilename` are both blocking functions, i.e. the function must be completed before further code is executed. The easiest way to avoid this problem is by using `threading` to create a thread which executes all the `pyautogui` functions separate from the main thread.

## functional_tests.py with pyautogui

```py
class TestOrganizeAttendance(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        ...

    def tearDown(self):
        ...

    def automate_file_dialogue(self, filepath):
        while "explorer.exe" not in [p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()]:    #Wait for the file dialogue to open
            continue
        directory, filename = os.path.split(filepath)
        pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'd')    #Keyboard shortcut to focus the address bar
        pyautogui.typewrite(directory)
        pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
        pyautogui.hotkey('tab')
        pyautogui.hotkey('tab')
        pyautogui.hotkey('tab')    #Repeatedly press TAB to remove focus from the address bar
        pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'n')    #Keyboard shortcut to focus the file name
        pyautogui.hotkey(filename)
        pyautogui.hotkey('enter')

    def test_attendance_organizer_window_operation(self):
        ...
        filepath = os.path.abspath(
            os.path.join('tests', 'sample_attendance.csv'))
        upload_thread = threading.Thread(
            target=self.automate_file_dialogue, args=(filepath,))
        upload_thread.start()
        upload_thread.start()
        self.assertTrue(os.path.exists(filepath))
        self.organizer.upload_file_button.invoke()
        self.assertIn(
            "explorer.exe", [p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()])
        upload_thread.join()
        ...
        filepath = os.path.abspath(
            os.path.join('tests', 'new_sample_attendance'))
        download_thread = threading.Thread(
            target=self.automate_file_dialogue, args=(filepath,))
        download_thread.start()
        self.assertFalse(os.path.exists(filepath))
        self.organizer.download_file_button.invoke()
        self.assertIn(
            "explorer.exe", [p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter()])
        download_thread.join()
```